# How to set Database Recover Mode to Full for all databases?

Tags: sql-server

Using a command similar to:

```
ALTER DATABASE test0402er2Y8 SET RECOVERY FULL
GO
```

How can I automatically execute this on all databases in server that are in simple mode now (using SQL Server 2012) ?

Thanks

Comment: How many database are you talking about? This seems like a very risky thing unless you have some sort of backup plan devised to handle these databases.

Answer (score 9):

> How can I automatically execute this on all databases in server that are in simple mode now (using SQL Server 2012) ?

Below T-SQL will help you. It will check for `ONLINE` databases with `SIMPLE`  recovery model and will print TSQL to change it into FULL Recovery mode. Run below code in TEXT Mode -- SSMS **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>**. Once you are happy, run the output generated  from another session :

```
set nocount on
go

if exists (
        select 1
        from sys.databases
        where recovery_model_desc = 'SIMPLE'
            and state_desc = 'ONLINE'
        )
begin
    print '-- You are setting up database to FULL recovery mode. '
    print '-- Make sure you take first full backup and then schedule LOG BACKUPS for proper transaction log maintenance !'

    select 'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' SET RECOVERY FULL with ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;'
    from sys.databases
    where recovery_model_desc = 'SIMPLE' -- since you only want SIMPLE recovery model databases to get changed to FULL recovery.
            and state_desc = 'ONLINE'
end
else
    select 'ALL the databases are in FULL RECOVERY MODE - Make sure you take proper LOG BACKUPS !!'
```

**NOTE :** For any databases that are newly created, its **better to change the recovery model of `model` database to FULL**, so that the new databases that are created inherit the FULL recovery setting from model database.

Worth mentioning : [Why Does the Transaction Log Keep Growing or Run Out of Space?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29829/why-does-the-transaction-log-keep-growing-or-run-out-of-space), since you are going to switch to FULL recovery and if you dont take care of your transaction log, then you will end up with a bloated transaction log. Read the answer linked for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **Cursor** for that like this:

```
DECLARE @DBName VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(255)

DECLARE FULLRECOVERY CURSOR FOR   
SELECT name  
FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id > 4 and recovery_model_desc = 'SIMPLE'

OPEN FULLRECOVERY 
FETCH NEXT FROM FULLRECOVERY INTO @DBName 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @SQL = 'ALTER DATABASE [' + @DBName + '] SET RECOVERY FULL' 
    PRINT @SQL 
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql 
    FETCH next FROM FULLRECOVERY INTO @DBName 

END 

CLOSE FULLRECOVERY 
DEALLOCATE FULLRECOVERY
```

More info about this script I wrote my post here:
http://www.pigeonsql.com/single-post/2016/12/20/How-to-Change-Recovery-Model-to-Simple-or-Full-for-All-Users-databases

Answer (score 1):

What if you use `sp_msforeachdb` like

```
exec sp_msforeachdb 'alter database ? set recovery full'
```

Here's a [Nice Script written using cursor](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1162703-391-1.aspx#bm1162705)

Comment: No, [please don't use or recommend `sp_msforeachdb`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/). It is undocumented, unsupported, and has a bug where it can skip databases with no warning or error message.